# methods of proof, discrete mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics

"Disprove: For all integers $r, m,$ and $n$, if $r$ divides $mn$ then either $r$ divides $m$ or $r$ divides $n$."

I am not sure if I am on the right track

To disprove I try the negation of a statement: " For some integers $r, m,$ and $n,$ if $r$ divides $mn$ then neither $r$ divides $m$ nor $r$ divides $n$.

then I assume with the Constructive proof that $m=3, n=5, r=15,$ In this case $r$ does not divide $m$ or $n$, as $r>m, r>n$.

However I don't like the reasoning I have here. Is it that simple or there better method to disprove statement?

Comment: I believe you just need to give one counter example in order to disprove this statement

Comment: Note: the theorem holds only if $r$ is a prime. This case is called Euclid's Lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done just fine! You have disproven the statement. You need only one counterexample to disprove it.

Since the statement is about *all* triplets of integers, we can disprove the statement by showing that there exists $r, m,n \in \mathbb Z$ such that the proposition fails.

Your counterexample is as fine as any other. My first thought was the following:

Put $$r = 6, m=2, n= 3$$

Then $$6 \mid 2\cdot 3, \text{ but }\, 6\not\mid 2 \text{ and } 6 \not\mid 3$$

To repeat: just a single counter-example for which a statement fails, is exactly how to disprove a given universal statement.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest counterexample is $4|4$ but $4$ does not divide $2$ or $2$